# google maps api centers to right location but arrow points to different one

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Maps API.  It's working for the most part, except I can't get the arrow to point to the right place.  Here's my code:

```
<div id="map1" style="height: 200px"></div>
<script>
    function createInfoWindowContent() {
      return ['the place', 'the city'].join('<br>');
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    function init() {
        // Options for Google map
        // More info see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
        var mapOptions1 = {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.366012, -71.098702)
            // Style for Google Maps

        };

        // Get all html elements for map
        var mapElement1 = document.getElementById('map1');

        // Create the Google Map using elements
        var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapElement1, mapOptions1);

          var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent());
          coordInfoWindow.open(map1);

    }

</script>
```

The code above does correctly center the map at the right location, but the pointer is all the way at the left and not pointed towards the location.  Here's a screenshot:
[image: the place]

How do I move the pointer?  I'm sure the answer is simple but I'm having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

The second object to the open method takes an anchor object:

```
coordInfoWindow.open(map1,{position:map1.getCenter()})
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow

Answer (score 1):

You can set the position of an infoWindow with an InfoWindowOptions object or the setPosition(LatLng) method. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

Comment: Thanks.  Where does the setposition method go?

Comment: Go? Put 'coordInfoWindow.setContent(new google.maps.LatLng(42.366012, -71.098702));' anywhere after the info window's been created, I'd assume.

Comment: Before the coordInfoWindow.open() call

Comment: ^That would be good. I believe you can use setPosition after it's been opened to change its position too though, if you ever want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Srt the position of the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow) using its .setPosition method:

```
var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent());
coordInfoWindow.setPosition(mapOptions1.center);
coordInfoWindow.open(map1);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f86edaLw/1/)

or set it in its constructor:

```
var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:createInfoWindowContent(), 
  position: mapOptions1.center
});
coordInfoWindow.open(map1);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f86edaLw/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function createInfoWindowContent() {
  return ['the place', 'the city'].join('<br>');
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

function init() {
  // Options for Google map
  // More info see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
  var mapOptions1 = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.366012, -71.098702)
      // Style for Google Maps

  };

  // Get all html elements for map
  var mapElement1 = document.getElementById('map1');

  // Create the Google Map using elements
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(mapElement1, mapOptions1);

  var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent());
  coordInfoWindow.setPosition(mapOptions1.center);
  coordInfoWindow.open(map1);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map1" style="height: 200px"></div>
```